# Random First Page

Tags: errors

Every tex files output pdf has a strange first page.
[image]

I am also including a mwe

```
\documentclass{aims}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amscd}
\def\typeofarticle{article}
\def\currentvolume{7}
\def\currentissue{x}
\def\currentyear{2022}
\def\currentmonth{Received date 27 September 2022, Accepted date }
\def\ppages{xxx--xxx}
\def\Received{}
\def\Revised{}
\def\Accepted{}
\def\Published{}


\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\essinf}{ess\,inf}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1\hfill \hspace{-0.2cm}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\eps}[1]{{#1}_{\varepsilon}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\essnorm}[1]{\norm{#1}_{\ess}}
\newcommand{\Lim}[1]{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{$\displaystyle \lim_{#1}\;$}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sgn}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
blah blah blah blah
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do not ignore error messages, tex is all in math mode, most likely misuse of `_` somewhere. There is nothing random here it is the source code of \mathcolor, but if you show no code or your log file, it is impossible to debug your problem.

Comment: It is happening with every code I am writing. Error messages are below:

Comment: \mathcolor allowed only in math mode. ...f_math:F { \non@alpherr {\mathcolor\space}

Comment: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model `##1'. \IfValueTF{#1} { \color[#1]{#2}

Comment: xcolor error is common in all codes. I don't know what is this.

Comment: Document class `aims` doesn't seem to be at CTAN, and the errors are coming from the class.  Where can it be found?

Comment: It is on AIMS Mathematics journal's website.

Comment: The code you provide does not result in the problem you describe. If you use `\begin{abstract}` you need to provide `\title{}`, `\author{}` and `\shortauthors{}` in this class, otherwise you will get errors. But even if I add these, I cannot reproduce your problem. Probably unrelated: `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` can be found twice in your preamble.

Comment: I found the template [here](https://www.aimspress.com/math/news/solo-detail/instructionsforauthors). I am not sure whether this is the file the OP uses, though.

Comment: please show the log you get on that test. Is that really _minimal_ is the line `\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}` required for example? It really helps debugging if you only have lines required. Is it only a problem with the non standard `aims` class, or can you show the problem with `article` ?

Comment: When I run the code on overleaf, everything works fine. I think something went wrong with my miktex .

Comment: if you showed your log as requested we could probably debug, otherwise if you update miktex and the problem goes I guess we can close here.

Comment: how to show log it has many lines?